# Infobright Queries

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse, infobright, column-oriented

I have a fact table in Infobright that has around 40 million rows. Running a query on that table, like the one shown below, takes well over 10 minutes.

```
SELECT pat_key,
   COUNT(c_id)
FROM my_fact_table
GROUP BY pat_key
ORDER BY COUNT(c_id) DESC
LIMIT 50;

Duration/Fetch = 334.528 sec / 0.094 sec
```

Any ideas why and how to tune this?

Btw, the hardware spec is AWS m1.large. So network latency aside, this is still a significant time interval.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, can you provide the DDL especially for pat_key and c_id?

Secondly, are you running Infobright Enterprise Edition or the Community Edition?

Thirdly, can you pull the bh.err log?  To do so, open brighthouse.ini (in your data directory), set ControlMessages=5, and restart the service.  Then, run this query.  The file bh.err should include a lot of information about the execution of this query.  Once you've done so, can you paste it here.

Finally, just looking solely on the query:
SELECT pat_key,
   COUNT(c_id) as thecnt
FROM my_fact_table
GROUP BY pat_key
ORDER BY thecnt DESC
LIMIT 50;

The bh.err will tell a lot more!  Plus, you limit yourself to 2 cores on this instance; you're probably a bit processor constrained.  I look forward to seeing more.